# Visual C++ fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++-cli

Every time i try to run this program it gives me an error: *EDITED*

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

and another error

> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main

*EDITED*

Ui.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace Spammer2 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Ui
/// </summary>
public ref class Ui : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Ui(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Ui()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer1;
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 13);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(260, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 138);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button1->Text = L"Start";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(196, 138);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->button2->Text = L"Stop";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::button2_Click);
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(172, 112);
        this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
        this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->textBox2->TabIndex = 3;
        this->textBox2->Text = L"100";
        this->textBox2->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::textBox2_TextChanged);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(62, 115);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(104, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 4;
        this->label1->Text = L"Interval milliseconds:";
        this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::label1_Click);
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Ui::timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // Ui
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 173);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Name = L"Ui";
        this->Text = L"Spammereme V2";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             timer1->Start();
         }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             timer1->Stop();
         }
private: System::Void textBox2_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            timer1->Interval = System::Int32::Parse(textBox2->Text);
            SendKeys::Send(textBox1->Text);
            SendKeys::Send("{ENTER}");
         }
}
};
```

Ui.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Ui.h"
```

Comment: The compiler should also be telling you *exactly where the error is*. (E.g., it's on line 154 -- which of the above is line 154? Look there, and you'll find the problem.)

Comment: Something else that would help would be to consistently indent your code. That makes errors like this easier to spot. (Though in this case, assuming Biffen's comment below is correct, it might not have helped much.)

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `;` after the class (second to last line).

Comment: This could do with being labelled CLI as well

Comment: If the linker is looking for _main then the problem is not in this code. It's in the main class or the project settings.

Comment: And how cna i find the problem and fix it?

Comment: Have you written a function called main? If so, add it to your project. If not, perhaps you should.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error will say the line number for the question you originally asked.
However, it looks like you have

```
namespace Spammer2 {

//lots of usings

public ref class Ui : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
//lots of other stuff
}
};
```

You need to end the class definition with a semicolon, not the namespace:

```
namespace Spammer2 {

//lots of usings

public ref class Ui : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
//lots of other stuff
}; //<-------
}  //<-------
```

**Edit:**

Since the question has now changed, if this is all your code add a `main` to UI.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Ui.h"

int main()
{
}
```